# Limiting user requests to a specefic url NODEJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, rate-limiting

I've got a NodeJS backend server that allows registered users to send a URL that will be later handled by a python scraper. Most of the time it works well, but if a user will abuse this function, some sites can block my server from sending them request.
Because this function is only available for registered users, I'm thinking that the requests limitation for that specific request can be done by limiting the user and not a ceratin IP or something like that.
Does anyone have an example or an idea for limiting user's request for a certain URL with nodejs \ mongodb?

Thanks!

Comment: [rate-limiter-flexible](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rate-limiter-flexible) package can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using express, you can take a look at: [Express Rate Limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit) middleware, and use it as in their documentation:

```
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");
 
const apiLimiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
  max: 100
});
 
// only apply to requests that begin with /api/
app.use("/api/", apiLimiter); //
```